# How can I refactor two similar functions in different classes to avoid code duplication in C# (Unity)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two similar functions in separate classes that share a lot of code. Both functions detect the closest enemy but differ only in the type of enemy they detect (Enemy and FriendlyTarget). Here's an example of the code:

```
public Transform DetectClosestEnemy(Character character)
{
            Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(character.transform.position, fightingDistance, enemyLayer);
    if (colliders.Length == 0)
    {
        target = null;
        return target;

    }
    //calculate distance from target, if it exists
    float currentDistanceToTarget = (target != null) ? Vector3.Distance(character.transform.position, target.transform.position) : Mathf.Infinity;

    foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
    {
        Enemy enemy = collider.GetComponent(characterToTargetType) as Enemy;
}

public Transform DetectClosestEnemy(Character character)
{
            Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(character.transform.position, fightingDistance, enemyLayer);
    if (colliders.Length == 0)
    {
        target = null;
        return target;

    }
    //calculate distance from target, if it exists
    float currentDistanceToTarget = (target != null) ? Vector3.Distance(character.transform.position, target.transform.position) : Mathf.Infinity;

    foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
    {
        FriendlyTarget enemy = collider.GetComponent(characterToTargetType) as FriendlyTarget;
}
```

As you can see, the code structure is almost identical, except for the type of enemy detected.

I want to avoid code duplication and make the code more maintainable. How can I refactor these functions to achieve that while still allowing them to work with different enemy types?

I've tried using generics, but I'm encountering issues with casting to the specific enemy type.

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You need a mapping between characters and characterToTargetType which indicates if the two characters are Friendly or enemies.  Once you solve that problem the solution to your problem is trivial.

Comment: Since you already have an idea, you'd better ask about the issues.

Comment: Pass in a parameter to say search for friend or foe

Answer (score 1):

if you have type when invoke method

```cs
public Transform DetectClosestEnemy<TEnemy>(Character character)
       where TEnemy: EnemyBaseClass
{
            Collider[] colliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(character.transform.position, fightingDistance, enemyLayer);
    if (colliders.Length == 0)
    {
        target = null;
        return target;

    }
    //calculate distance from target, if it exists
    float currentDistanceToTarget = (target != null) ? Vector3.Distance(character.transform.position, target.transform.position) : Mathf.Infinity;

    foreach (Collider collider in colliders)
    {
        Enemy enemy = collider.GetComponent(characterToTargetType) as TEnemy;
     }
}
```

Use this method like that:

```
var friendly = DetectClosestEnemy<FriendlyTarget>(character)
```

Comment: This is the right way of doing it - I just want to add that in order to use this method you would call it like this: `var friendly = DetectClosestEnemy<FriendlyTarget>(character)`. (I would add this info as an edit but stackoverflow isn't letting me right now).